# Angular: Access nativeElement of a component in another component

Tags: angular

```
<first-component #ref></first-component>
<second-component [data]="ref"></second-component>
```

I want to access the nativeElement of first-component in second-component, so I can do some positioning operations relative to first-component. How can I access the first-component's nativeElement in second component? As it is, the "ref" value refers to the FirstComponent instance (as expected).

Also, these two components don't have to have a parent-child or sibling relationship.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is wrapping both the first & second components in a parent component and accessing the `nativeElements` using `@ViewChild` or `@ViewChildren` decorators. Then, the parent component can assign any values of reference as desired.
In this case,

**parent.component.ts**:

```
@ViewChild('ref') public ref;
public refEl = this.ref.nativeElement;
```

**parent.component.html**:

```
<first-component #ref></first-component>
<second-component [data]="refEl"></second-component>
```